# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Azure CDN Standard Verizon

Tags: azure, https, cdn, http-redirect, azure-cdn

I am using a CDN in Azure and its a **Standard Verizon**. Is it possible to do the Automatic Redirection from HTTP to HTTPS?
I know that I can do this if the CDN is a Standard Azure CDN from Microsoft.

[Set up the Standard rules engine for Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine)

it is possible to do this with a **Standard Verizon** CDN because the **Rules Engine** tab is not available to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this feature **URL redirect/rewrite** is not available **Standard** Verizon CDN but you can upgrade it to the Azure CDN Verizon **Premium** tier. See [see Azure CDN product features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-features)

For more references:

- [Migrate an Azure CDN profile from Standard Verizon to Premium Verizon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-migrate)
- [Override HTTP behavior using the Azure CDN from Verizon Premium rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine)

Comment: Nancy, Could you please check this as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193825/enforce-http-to-https-in-azure-premium-verizon-cdn