# Enforce HTTP to HTTPS in Azure Premium Verizon CDN

Tags: azure, networking, cdn, azure-cdn

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine) link to convert all the HTTP endpoints to HTTPS.
However, it uses an option called

```
IF Request Protocol;
THEN
URL Redirect
```

`Request Protocol` is not available(I cannot see) in the CDN profile that I am trying to configure. I have attached a screenshot of the rule creation phase below.

[image: RuleBuilder]

Question 1

Where can I find the `Request Protocol` option on the CDN Config page?

Question 2

If `Request Protocol` is deprecated(or no longer available), how can I perform the mentioned task?

Answer (score 0):

The rules engine that's described in [that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine) is available only for **Standard Azure CDN from Microsoft**.

To redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Azure Premium Verizon CDN, you can follow the steps in [this blog](https://medium.com/azure-architects/configuring-azure-cdn-http-https-redirection-2a9e4aab0a77).

The rules can take up to 4 hours to become active. But it’s typically much faster.

Comment: Nancy, As I say in the question, the `Request Protocol` option is no longer there in the newer update.

Comment: You can select the Request- Request Scheme to HTTP in the UI in Premium Verizon CDN.

Comment: This answer links to a paywalled Medium article. Would you mind summarizing the main points?